# Perl - Replacing an array string with a numerical value

Tags: arrays, perl

So as a practice for learning perl, I decided to write a simple game of blackjack. I'm using an array for the card values. I want to be able to include jack, king and queen cards in the players card list however I also want to be able to use these cards for adding to 21. First thought I tried to use a variable however this doesn't seem to work.

The array: `@cards = (1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10,$ace ='ace',$jack ='jack', $queen ='queen', $king ='king'); #NOTE: Ace is 11 or 1`

```
    sub PrintPlayersCards
{
    $playerTotal = 0;
    print "PLAYERS CARDS:@playerCurCards\n";
    @cards[$jack] = 10;
    @cards[$queen] = 10;
    @cards[$king] = 10;
    grep {$playerTotal += $_} @playerCurCards;
    print "Your total is :$playerTotal\n";
    @cards[$king] = "King";
    @cards[$queen] = "queen";
    @cards[$jack] = "jack";
}
```

@playerCurCards is an array which stores the players cards. EG: 3 from the start and king from a hit etc.

Comment: ``$ace = 'ace'`` and the other similar will not translate to what you are doing. Why not instead of $ace put 'ace' or 11 ?

Comment: Also @cards[..] is incorrect, it should be $cards[..]

Comment: I have a separate function for determining what the ace does and it works, I just need to be able to get the king/jack/queen working. Also why should I use $cards[] when referencing an array?

Comment: For each card, you have **at least** two pieces of information to store: the card name and its numerical value(s). That calls for something more powerful than a simple array. Maybe a hash, with card names as the hash keys, and numerical values as the hash keys. There are other options as well, but that's a place to start if you're just learning.

Comment: Read about Perl arrays
http://perldoc.perl.org/perlintro.html#Arrays

Comment: Maybe using a hash is more helpful for your problem.

Comment: Have you read anything at all about Perl? You seem to be just guessing what might work.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could store it in a hash instead:

```
#!/usr/bin/perl

use strict;
use warnings;


my %cards = ('1'=> '1',
    '2' => '2',
    '3' => '3',
    '4' => '4',
    '5' => '5',
    '6' => '6',
    '7' => '7',
    '8' => '8',
    '9' => '9',
    '10' => '10',
    'jack' => '10',
    'king' => '10',
    'queen' => '10',
);

sub PrintPlayersCards {
    my $playerTotal = 0;
    my @hand = @_;
    print "PLAYERS CARD:\n";
    print "\t$_\n" foreach @hand;
    grep {$playerTotal += $cards{$_}} @hand;
    print "Your total is: $playerTotal\n";
}

#this is just to test it
my @playerCurCards = ('1', 'queen', 'king');
PrintPlayersCards(@playerCurCards);
```